# Why a npm command removes folders with the same names

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I have a library, inside the library folder I have an examples folder.

```
@company/lib/
|--examples/
   |--package.json
|--somefile.file
|--somefile.file
|--package.json
```

After run `npm install` inside `@company/lib/examples/` the project structure is:

```
@company/lib/
|--examples/
   |--package.json
   |--node_modules/
      |--@company/lib/
         |--examples/
|--somefile.file
|--somefile.file
|--package.json
```

I'm trying to remove:
`@company/lib/examples/node_modules/@company/lib/examples`

My npm command is:

```
"postinstall": "npm run clean:examples",
"clean:examples": "rm -rf node_modules/@company/lib/examples",
```

The problem is that it removes every `examples` folder, even the folder that it's in the root project and it only remains:

```
@company/lib/
|--somefile.file
|--somefile.file
|--package.json
```

**EDITED**: The library is a private module, and it works like `@company/lib/`

Comment: Following your steps and running the command manually works as expected. Can you provide any extra information to help us recreate your problem?

Comment: @JackZelig I have edited my question.

Comment: Sorry man, that still doesn't help reproduce your issue. I created the folder structure manually, added the `clean:examples` npm script to `@company/libexamples/package.json` and ran the task manually from within the containing directory. This worked as expected and deleted the correct folder. This means that a factor is in play that cannot be deduced from the info you posted.

Comment: I also tried the same as @JackZelig and it deleted the correctly folder too. I assumed that your `postinstall` and `clean:examples` scripts exists in the `package.json` located at  `@company/lib/examples/` and not in the `package.json` located at  `@company/lib/`? Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Yes, the `package.json` is located at `@company/lib/examples/`. I have explained the problem as it happens, I also have tried with other commands like `rm -rf ./node_modules/@company/lib/examples` but it stills deleting all folders with the same name. Indeed, this is like if the folder were a reference of the other folders. It's that I think. @RobC @Jack Zelig

Comment: To determine the path of what's considered the current working directory when the `postinstall` script executes you could temporarily replace the  `"clean:examples"` script with the following: `"clean:examples": "echo $PWD"` _(if running on bash)_ or `"clean:examples": "echo %CD%"` _(if running on Windows via cmd.exe or PowerShell)_. Then reinstall the pkg again and observe the path logged to the console. It should be the correct one ending `@company/lib/examples`. Does the logged path plus `node_modules/@company/lib/examples` (as per `rm -rf` script) equate to the correct complete path?

Comment: @RobC I ran as you said with `pwd` and it shows the correct path. `@company/lib/examples`. And yes, `node_modules/@company/lib/examples` is the correct complete path because it is a copy of `@company/lib/` inside `@company/lib/examples/node_modules/`.